# The effect of a temperature change on the fundamental frequency of a stretched string

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, frequency, string

I am curious about the effect of temperature on the frequency of say, a guitar string (stretched under a tension $F_T$ and of fixed length $L$). I wonder if someone here could check my work.

First of all, note that the fundamental frequency of such a string is given by $$f=\frac{1}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{F_T}{\mu}},$$ where $\mu=m/L$ is the linear mass density. I want to find $\frac{df}{dT}$, or the change in frequency with respect to temperature. We will assume that only $F_T(T)$ depends on temperature, and that $\mu$ and $L$ are constant.* $$\frac{df}{dT}=\frac{d}{dT}\left(\frac{1}{2 L}\sqrt{\frac{F_T(T)}{\mu}}\right)=\frac{1}{2 L\sqrt{\mu}}\frac{d}{DT}F_T^{1/2}(T)=\frac{1}{4L\sqrt{\mu}}F_T^{-1/2}(T)\cdot\frac{dF_T(T)}{dT}.  $$

It is left to find $F_T(T)$. Now, even though we assume the string to be a one dimensional object (in the original derivation of $f$), to account for the temperature change on the tension, we must consider that the string is actually a wire with cross sectional area $A$.** The way we can relate temperature to tension is through Young's modulus. Though the length is not changing, we may imagine the change in length the string would *like* to experience were it not bounded, for a given tension,*** is given by $$\frac{\Delta L}{L}=\alpha \Delta T.$$ Note that this is also the expression for stress, $\varepsilon$. The strain is given by $$\sigma=\frac{F_T(T)}{A}.$$ We may now consider Young's modulus: $$ E=\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon}=\frac{F_T(T)/A}{\alpha \Delta T}, \ \therefore F_T(T)= E A \alpha \Delta T= E A \alpha (T-T_0)  $$ for some initial temperature $T_0$. $$\frac{d{F_T(T)}}{dT}=E A \alpha(1-T_0.) $$ Now we may substitute back into $\frac{df}{dT}$:

$$\frac{df}{dT}=\frac{1}{4L\sqrt{\mu}}F_T^{-1/2}(T)\cdot\frac{dF_T(T)}{dT}. =\frac{1}{4L\sqrt{\mu}}\left(E A \alpha (T-T_0)      \right)^{-1/2}\cdot\left(E A \alpha(1-T_0)\right) =\frac{1-T_0}{4L}\sqrt{\frac{E A \alpha}{\mu(T-T_0)}} .$$ For a given $T, T_0$, we may set $$\frac{1-T_0}{\sqrt{T-T_0}}=c$$ as a constant, meaning that $$\left.\frac{df}{dT}\right|_{T} \propto\frac{1}{4L}\sqrt{\frac{E A\alpha}{\mu}}. $$

Am I anywhere close?

*Is this assumption correct?

**How about this assumption?

***Is *this* assumption correct? This one is the most bothersome.

I was really hoping for a nice monomial expression without those difference terms, so something feels off base here. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be valid to simply write $\varepsilon=\alpha T$? In that case I get $$\frac{df}{dT}=\frac{\sqrt{E A\alpha}}{4L\sqrt{\mu T}},$$ which is a much more elegant expression.

Comment: The frequency should go *down* if the temperature is larger, so $df/dT$ should be negative.

Comment: That's a good point. It looks like in general $1-T_0$ will be negative.

Comment: The units don't work out there. There shouldn't be a $1-T_0$; the $T_0$ should have gone to zero when the derivative of $F_T$ was taken. Furthermore, the fact that there's a $\sqrt{T-T_0}$ makes we worried, because if the temperature goes down from $T_0$, that's a problem. Perhaps you've made use somewhere of an assumption that $T$ necessarily increases, but I can't see it. Otherwise, I don't really have a good way to assess this process. It *seems* plausible, but then again, making both $\mu$ and $L$ be constant seems a little strange. They should both actually change.

Comment: Indeed, the string tension decreases *because* the string gets a little longer, allowing it to "sag" a little.

Comment: March, yes that's an obvious oversight on my part. There should be no $T_0$ term in $dF_T/dT$ at all. I'm not sure how to resolve the issue with $\sqrt{T-T_0}$.