# Tension vs. Temperature in a stretched string

Tags: temperature, string

Is there a nice way to express tension in a stretched string of fixed length (like a piano string) as a function of temperature?

Comment: You have asked a very similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673935/307237). If you would like to change the previous question, [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788) it; otherwise the current question may be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a different question. The first shows my attempt to derive the dependence of string *frequency* on temperature. This is asking about the dependence of string *tension* on temperature. It's an intermediate step in answering my first question, and I'm not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the Young's modulus of the (steel?) string and its coefficient of the thermal expansion.  Use  the expansion coefficient to compute  the length of the string at temperature $T$ and how much you have to stretch it to the length it needs. Then use Young's modulus to compute the tension needed to stretch it this much.

Comment: I've been confused since the string length isn't really allowed to change, but thermal expansion is all I have to work with. So the idea is to find out how much the length would change if it were allowed to, and find the corresponding tension change that gives the same Young's modulus with the length unchanged?

Comment: Precisely. Use my method and compute the tension change.